# Is it possible to target or change SVG favicon on Firefox when tab is inactive without using `window.onblur()`?

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg, favicon

I'm having issues in firefox with the favicon I'm using. The logo is black, which is fine when the tab is active, but when the tab is inactive, the tab's background is dark and the logo becomes barely visible.

I was wondering if you could target this somehow using a CSS psuedo-selector? I know I could potentially detect the tab change using `window.onblur()` with JS, but it's pretty far from a flawless solution, so I'm hesitant on using it as such.

I'm keen to find a solution that works using HTML/CSS and I'm happy to concede that there may not be a solution, but I was wondering if anyone had come across this issue and what was their workaround (if any)?

Comment: tabs are browser chrome, you can only target chrome (except in limited ways like favicon and titles) with an extension, not from a web page. favicons cannot run scripts.

Comment: Yep, this is why I stated I didn't want to use JS. It's quite annoying for companies that use black logos though... Not ideal. The reason why I asked for a CSS solution is because there is a  CSS pseudo-selector that can target dark mode, so you can change the fill properties of the SVG logo using that selector should a user have dark mode initiliased; and I wondered if there was a similar selector available for inactive tabs